# Ошибка too many values to unpack (expected 3) при сплите столбца

Tags: python, pandas, дата, datetime

При использовании метода split для DataFrame Views появляется ошибка: `too many values to unpack (expected 3)`.

Задача: разбить столбец Date на 3 столбца year, month, day чтобы потом в дату перевести. Что делаю не так, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Код:

```
year, month, day = views.Date.str.split('/')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какое значение в `views.Date.str` покажите.

Comment: У вас в результате split получается список состоящий более чем из 3 элементов.

Comment: Nikmoon, добавил скрин.

Comment: godva, в том и проблема. Переменных три и я ожидал, что в результате сплита по "/" получатся 3 столбца, но возвращается ошибка.

Comment: `views.Date = pd.to_datetime(views.Date)` и не надо ничего разделять и собирать потом опять в `datetime`

Comment: MaxU, да, вы правы!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отвечая на ваш вопрос о `.str.split(...)`:

в `.str.split(..., expand=False)` по умолчанию `expand=False`, т.е. он вернет `pandas.Series` где элементами будут списки:

```
In [49]: df.date.str.split('/')
Out[49]:
0    [2016, 01, 09]
1    [2016, 11, 11]
2    [2016, 12, 30]
Name: date, dtype: object
```

если указать `expand=True`, то вернется `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
In [50]: df.date.str.split('/', expand=True)
Out[50]:
      0   1   2
0  2016  01  09
1  2016  11  11
2  2016  12  30
```

еще можно воспользоваться `.str.extract()` и указать имена столбцов:

```
In [51]: df.date.str.extract(r'(?P<year>\d{4})[-/\.](?P<month>\d{2})[-/\.](?P<day>\d{2})', expand=True)
Out[51]:
   year month day
0  2016    01  09
1  2016    11  11
2  2016    12  30

In [52]: split = df.date.str.extract(r'(?P<year>\d{4})[-/\.](?P<month>\d{2})[-/\.](?P<day>\d{2})', expand=True)

In [53]: split
Out[53]:
   year month day
0  2016    01  09
1  2016    11  11
2  2016    12  30
```

Comment: MaxU , спасибо!